# Django - How to load a child templates in base.html div element properly

Tags: jquery, python, django, python-3.x

I am having problem by loading a child template inside a `<div class="app-content">`. It loads the whole `base.html`again with the child working `{% block title %}` but fails to display `div` element with text. I use `jquery` to call the child templates.

Here is my templates structure:

```
/templates
../payroll
..../dashboard
......index.html
..../workspace
......index.html
....base.html
```

## base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Payroll - Dashboard{% endblock %}</title>

        {% load staticfiles %}

        {% block stylesheet %}
           ... STYLESHEETS ...
        {% endblock %}
    </head>

    <body>

        ... HEADER ...

        <!---->
        <ul class="uk-nav">
            <li class="bvc-menu-item-active" >
                <a id="bvc-dashboard" href="{% url 'payroll:dashboard' %}">
                    <i class="fa fa-tachometer fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <span class="bvc-menu-item" style="margin-left: 25px;">Dashboard</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="" >
                <a id="bvc-workspace" href="{% url 'payroll:workspace' %}">
                    <i class="fa fa-building fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <span  class="bvc-menu-item" style="margin-left: 28px;">Workspace</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- End of sidebar -->

        <!---->
        <div class="app-content">

        </div>
        <!-- End of app-content -->

        ... FOOTER ....
    </body>

    {% block scripts %}
        <script src="{% static 'payroll/js/jquery-2.2.1.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'payroll/js/uikit.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'payroll/js/bvc-index.js' %}"></script>
    {% endblock %}
</html>
```

## dashboard/index.html

```
{% extends "payroll/base.html" %}
{% block title %}Payroll - Dashboard{% endblock %}
<div>
    This is a dashboard index page.
</div>
```

## workspace/index.html

```
{% extends "payroll/base.html" %}
{% block title %}Payroll - Workspace{% endblock %}
<div>
    This is a workspace index!
</div>
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import generic

class HomeIndexView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = "payroll/base.html"

class DashboardIndexView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = "payroll/dashboard/index.html"

class WorkspaceIndexView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = "payroll/workspace/index.html"
```

## urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'payroll'
urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /payroll/
    url(r'^$', views.HomeIndexView.as_view(), name='home'),
    # ex: /payroll/dashboard/
    url(r'^dashboard/$', views.DashboardIndexView.as_view(), name='dashboard'),
    # ex: /payroll/workspace/
    url(r'^workspace/$', views.WorkspaceIndexView.as_view(), name='workspace'),
]
```

## bvc-index.js (used to handle click event to load child template)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#bvc-dashboard').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();

       var url = $(this).attr("href");
       $('.app-content').load(url);
   });

   $('#bvc-workspace').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();

       var url = $(this).attr("href");
       $('.app-content').load(url);
   });

});
```

Here is the output image.
[image]

Comment: Its showing base.html because you have extended it in the child templates. If your child templates are always called through a jquery and doesn't have an independent page(like modal popups) then remove `{% extends %}`.

Comment: It is possible to show child templates via `<a>` link without using jquery sir? and wow it is working but sadly the `{% block title %}` won't

Comment: Well in that case either make two views (not a good idea) OR replace the whole html content of base.html with the child through jquery (base is still in the child).

Comment: i think it is not a good practice sadly